# adding an editable text layer to a canvas using kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having some trouble in adding text from an input box into my canvas, I have successfully added another layer, however my text doesn't seem to add to the canvas and I am baffled as to why not.

I have included a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nby9k/) link,

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Melissa

```
        $("#addbutton").click(function () {

                    // simple label
        var label = new Kinetic.Label({
            x: 20,
            y: 20,
            draggable: true
        });

        label.add(new Kinetic.Tag({
            fill: 'green'
        }));

        label.add(new Kinetic.Text({
            text: $("#newtext").val(),
            fontFamily: 'Verdana',
            fontSize: 18,
            padding: 10,
            fill: 'white'
        }));

        textLayer.add(label);

        textLayer.draw();

    });
```